# Planned contrasts in emmeans

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I would like to compute a specific subset of planned contrasts using emmeans, but have trouble coding these.

In my sample dataset, I have two conditions, "drugA" and "drugB". There are 6 animals A-F and the weight of each animal has been measured 3 times under the influence of each drug.

```
id <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),6)
drug <- c(rep(c("drugA"), 18), rep(c("drugB"), 18))
time <- rep(rep(1:3, each = 6),2)
value <- c(rnorm(6, 1, 0.4), rnorm(6, 3, 0.5), rnorm(6, 6, 0.8), rnorm(6, 1.1, 0.4), rnorm(6, 0.8, 0.2), rnorm(6, 1, 0.6))
df <- data.frame(id,drug, time, value)

df$id <- as.factor(df$id) 
df$drug <- as.factor(df$drug)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)
stats <- lmer(value ~ drug*time + drug + time + (1|id), data = df)
summary(stats)

emm <- emmeans(stats, list(pairwise ~ drug + time), adjust = "tukey") 
emm
```

However, I would **only** like to calculate the following contrasts:

DrugA, time1 vs. DrugB, time1

DrugA, time2 vs. DrugB, time2

DrugA, time3 vs. DrugB, time3

DrugA, time1 vs. time2

DrugA, time2 vs. time3

DrugB, time1 vs. time2

DrugB, time2 vs. time3

How do I have to code these contrasts? Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried getting started writing out the vectors of 0 and 1 that represent the group means for each drug:time combination? Or is that where you're stuck? You'll base these vectors on the output of emmeans. I'd make emm without the "pairwise" and start building my vectors from there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I think the challenge is to get from the output (grid has 3 cols and 16 rows, what is the third col?) to the contrasts...

Comment: Looks like you made good progress! Yes, I see the difficulty. I think figuring out the plus/minus 1 or averaging over another factor can be hard, which is why I teach students to make a vector that represents each combined mean and then do math with the vectors to represent their desired comparisons. :)

Comment: Hmm...I still cannot solve the following issue: it seems puzzling that estimates, SE, and p values are sometimes identical. Is something wrong there?

Comment: Since you didn't allow for an interaction in the model, it makes sense to me that differences of, e.g., A vs B for time 1 is the same as it is for time 2.  Your model says there is one overall difference between A and B regardless of time.

Comment: Oh lord...I should get some sleep and give my brain a rest it seems. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue here is to look at the result grid of emmeans. The two first columns are the basis for the formulation of contrasts, each line represents one combination of factors.

```
emm <- emmeans(stats, list(~ drug + time)) # not used afterwards, but to check result Grid

con <- list(
  DrugA1_DrugB1 = c(1,-1,0,0,0,0),
  DrugA2_DrugB2 = c(0,0,1,-1,0,0),
  DrugA3_DrugB3 = c(0,0,0,0,-1,1),

  DrugA1_DrugA2 = c(1,0,-1,0,0,0),
  DrugA2_DrugA3 = c(0,0,1,0,-1,0),

  DrugB1_DrugB2 = c(0,1,0,-1,0,0),
  DrugB2_DrugB3 = c(0,0,0,1,0,-1)
)
```

The following then gives you exactly those contrasts.

```
 emm <- emmeans(stats, list(~ drug + time), contr = con, adjust = "mvt")
```

Comment: Another issue is that I would like to use the **multcomp** package for more powerful p-val adjustments.

    emm <- emmeans(stats, list(~ drug + time))
    summary(as.glht(contrast(emm, con)), test = adjusted("free"))

However, this gives the error message

> Error in contrast.emmGrid(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Nonconforming number of contrast coefficients

Comment: In this answer, ``adjust = “tukey”` will be ignored because that adjustment is inappropriate except for pairwise comparisons. Use `adjust = “mvt”` to get exactly the same adjustment that multcomp uses as the single-step adjustment. You can also use `as.glht()` to get multcomp to do it directly. See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contrast()` for that:

```r
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

id <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),6)
drug <- c(rep(c("drugA"), 18), rep(c("drugB"), 18))
time <- rep(rep(1:3, each = 6),2)
value <- c(rnorm(6, 1, 0.4), rnorm(6, 3, 0.5), rnorm(6, 6, 0.8), rnorm(6, 1.1, 0.4), rnorm(6, 0.8, 0.2), rnorm(6, 1, 0.6))
df <- data.frame(id,drug, time, value)

df$id <- as.factor(df$id) 
df$drug <- as.factor(df$drug)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)
stats <- lmer(value ~ drug*time + drug + time + (1|id), data = df)

emm <- emmeans(stats, ~ drug + time)
emm
#>  drug  time emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  drugA 1      1.16 0.187 28.8    0.778     1.55
#>  drugB 1      1.05 0.187 28.8    0.666     1.43
#>  drugA 2      3.30 0.187 28.8    2.917     3.68
#>  drugB 2      0.84 0.187 28.8    0.457     1.22
#>  drugA 3      5.99 0.187 28.8    5.602     6.37
#>  drugB 3      1.30 0.187 28.8    0.920     1.69
#> 
#> Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

contrast(emm, method = "pairwise", by = "time")
#> time = 1:
#>  contrast      estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  drugA - drugB    0.113 0.253 25  0.446  0.6593 
#> 
#> time = 2:
#>  contrast      estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  drugA - drugB    2.461 0.253 25  9.745  <.0001 
#> 
#> time = 3:
#>  contrast      estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  drugA - drugB    4.683 0.253 25 18.545  <.0001 
#> 
#> Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger

contrast(emm, method = "consec", by = "drug")
#> drug = drugA:
#>  contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  2 - 1       2.139 0.253 25  8.471  <.0001 
#>  3 - 2       2.685 0.253 25 10.634  <.0001 
#> 
#> drug = drugB:
#>  contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  2 - 1      -0.209 0.253 25 -0.828  0.6244 
#>  3 - 2       0.463 0.253 25  1.834  0.1383 
#> 
#> Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
#> P value adjustment: mvt method for 2 tests
```